# NVIDIA Driver 515.76 installation failed on Debian with kernel 6.0.0-rc7-amd64

Tags: debian, kernel, nvidia, dkms

My NVIDIA 515.76 driver installation failed, because dkms fails to build the modules. I post here the part of the nvidia-make.log and nvidia-installer log where it describes the errors for further information.
This one is the nvidia-make log:

```
ld:scripts/module.lds:61: syntax error
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-rc7-common/scripts/Makefile.modfinal:59: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.76/build/nvidia-drm.ko] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-rc7-common/scripts/Makefile.modpost:134: __modpost] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-rc7-common/Makefile:1766: modules] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-rc7-amd64'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:222: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.0.0-rc7-common'
make: *** [Makefile:82: modules] Error 2
```

And this one is from the installer log:

```
ERROR: Failed to run `/usr/sbin/dkms build -m nvidia -v 515.76 -k 6.0.0-rc7-amd64`: Sign command: /usr/lib/linux-kbuild-6.0/scripts/sign-file
Signing key: /var/lib/dkms/mok.key
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/dkms/mok.pub
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j2 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=6.0.0-rc7-amd64 
 modules..............................................(bad exit status: 2)
 Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.0.0-rc7-amd64 (x86_64)
 Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.76/build/make.log for more information.
 -> error.
 ERROR: Failed to install the kernel module through DKMS. No kernel module was 
 installed; please try installing again without DKMS, or check the DKMS logs for more 
 information.
 ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' 
 for details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README 
 available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```